# How do you automatically set the foreign key on a new object from an ActiveRecord relationship if the class names don't match?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following class is a subclass of Quote using single table inheritance.

```
class BuyQuote < Quote
  has_many :shipment_quotes, foreign_key: :quote_id
  has_many :shipments, through: :shipment_quotes
end
```

I'd like to create a shipment using the standard ActiveRecord `new` method.

```
quote = BuyQuote.create
shipment = quote.shipments.new
```

But, the relationship is not being set between the `shipment` and the `quote`. I assume that this is due to the class name being different than expected, but I'm not sure.

How can I modify the ActiveRecord relationship so that this will work?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some syntax errors in your posted code and potentially an incorrect table name.  If the lookup table doesn't need any additional attributes (other than relating the Shipment to the Quote), I would just use the simplistic has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.  This depends on if you plan to have a shipment associated with more than one quote.

```
class BuyQuote < Quote
  has_many :shipments_quotes, :foreign_key => :quote_id
  has_many :shipments, :through => :shipments_quotes
end
```

or with habtm relationship:

```
class BuyQuote < Quote
  has_and_belongs_to_many :shipments, :foreign_key => :quote_id
end
```

Another issue could be because you are instantiating a Quote class, which you aren't showing the definition for.  You seem to be defining the "shipments" relationship for the BuyQuote class, but not for the parent class Quote.

Maybe try:

```
quote = BuyQuote.create
shipment = quote.shipments.new
```

Comment: Right. I should have typed `BuyQuote.new`. That was just an error in the question. But, it doesn't seem to matter if I define the relationship to `shipments` in the superclass or not.